# I want to change one of xAxis label text on the basis of the condition in line graph in pentaho CDE

Tags: charts, pentaho, pentaho-cde

I want to change one of xAxis label text on the basis of the condition in line graph in pentaho CDE.

I am using pentaho CDE version 5.0 and I generate  a  line graph on the basis of dynamic values. Now those values became the x and y axis of the graph.

Now I want to do that on the basis of condition want to change the one of the label caption.

For example. X Axis lables are "India, US, China, England" and on the basis of condition like if China come in the label it automatic became hongkong.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this problem...

Find the following steps.

Go to Charts advanced properties.

Then open the **Extention point** and add the following parameters

**baseAxisLabel_text** and in value type the following function.

```
function(a) 
{ 
  var str = this.scene.atoms.category.label; 
  if(str=="Feb")
  {
      str="February";     /*Either we can use this option */
  }
  else
  {
      str=str;
  }
  return str.replace("Jan", "January").replace("Mar", "March"); /*or we can use this option */

}
```